# Issues getting osddm to boot

Tags: database, oracle, modeling

Issues getting osddm to start..

Followed the following stack threads; without much luck;

[Installing Oracle Datamodeler on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41928566/installing-oracle-datamodeler-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: As an aside from my answer, please not that "issues getting .... to start" and "Followed .. threads ... wihout much luck" is devoid of actionable information.  Whenever posting about something that "doesn't work", you need to include relevant error codes or other diagnostic output.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle was never designed to run on Debian based Linux, such as Ubuntu. As you can plainly see from the cited 'directions', it's installing on ubuntu is a hack, at best.  My recommendation is to install Oracle VirtualBox, use that to create a vm, and install Oracle Linux on that vm, then go from there.  That's exactly what I've done on the ubuntu laptop I am writing this from.  For more details, see https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/category/personal-test-systems/